the infinite category of pullback squares in an infinite stable category is also stable
I am currently reading Lurie's paper infinite stable category, in the proof of proposition 4.4, to show that every pushout square in an infinite stable category $C$ is also a pullback, he considers the subcategory $D\subset Fun(\triangle^{1}\times \triangle^{1},C)$ to be the full subcategory spanned by the pullback squares. Then there is a statement that $D$ is stable under finite limits and under translation, so it's also stable.
As translation $X\rightarrow X[-1]=\Omega(X)$ where $\Omega$ is the loop functor is an equivalence functor for stable infinite category $C$, it must take pullback to pullback. Thus it remains to prove that $D$ is stable under finite limits, how do we do this?

This follows from the fact that limits commute with limits (and that limits in functor categories are computed objectwise). I will write
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
00 @>>> 10\\
@VVV @VVV\\
01 @>>> 11
\end{CD}
$$ for the category $\Delta^1\times\Delta^1$. If we have a finite diagram $F\colon\mathcal{I}\to\mathcal{D}$ then the statement that limits commute with limits means that
$$
(\mathrm{lim}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\,F_i)(10)\times_{(\mathrm{lim}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\,F_i)(11)}(\mathrm{lim}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\,F_i)(01)\simeq\mathrm{lim}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}(F_i(10)\times_{F_i(11)}F_i(01))\\
\simeq\mathrm{lim}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\,(F_i(00))\simeq(\mathrm{lim}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\,F_i)(00),
$$
so the square $\mathrm{lim}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\,F_i$ is also a pullback square in $\mathcal{C}$.
